# Change the fee on Multibit

Tags: transaction-fees, multibit

The transactions-fee is set to 0.0001 btc in Multibit classic. Can I set the fee to 0.2 or 0.3 mBTC? Where is the java class that I must change to upgrade the fee? What is the var or const to change?

Comment: I haven't tried, that's why I'll not answer but (if this is the right repo for mb classic), this seems to set the tx fee https://github.com/bitcoin-solutions/multibit/blob/9e0891aacd357e13d1c775bf89f682058c72c180/src/main/java/org/multibit/viewsystem/swing/view/components/FeeSlider.java#L25 - also It seems a swing component that renders a slider, are you sure you can't set the fee from the preferences trough a range select/slider?

Comment: In the most recent version of MultiBit Classic there is a slider that you can use to adjust the fee. You can adjust it from 0.000 01 BTC/KB of transaction (too low for today's network) to 0.000 5 BTC/KB

Comment: Tanks makevoid and tanks a lot Jim, I'm a usual user af bitcoin classic and have not noted the new feature.